# MVC ckeditor post editor value inline

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

Im using CKEditor 4.3.2 and Im going to use inline feature with MVC. So I want to send edited data to my controller through a button:

```
$('#savebutton').click(function () {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['texteditor'].getData();      
    $.post('@Url.Action("SaveData", "News")', { save: value }, function (data) {
    });
```

When I replace simple string data eg) "test" instead of value in this section,

> { save: value }

it works, but cause my real value is html type so controller's event do not fire.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSON and its solved. thanks to nobody :)

```
$('#savebutton').click(function () {        
    var text = CKEDITOR.instances['text'].getData();        
    var send = JSON.stringify({ 'text':text });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "News")',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: send
    });
});
```